# How does Linux kernel deal with Device not Available(DNA) to support Lazy FPU Save/Restore?

Tags: exception, linux-kernel, context-switch, fpu

[Lazy FPU Save/Restore](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3485131) gives an explanation about how Linux kernel deals with Device not Available(DNA) to support Lazy FPU Save/Restore:

> Under the lazy restore scheme, during task switch, the first FP
> instruction executed by a process generates a “Device not Available
> (DNA)” exception; the DNA exception handler then saves the current FPU
> context into the old task’s state save area and loads the new FPU
> context for the current process. In other words, loading of the FPU
> state is deferred until an FP instruction is invoked by the current
> task - Lazy FPU restore.

But I checked the exception [handler](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.295/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L751) for “Device not Available (DNA)”:

```
dotraplinkage void
do_device_not_available(struct pt_regs *regs, long error_code)
{
    RCU_LOCKDEP_WARN(!rcu_is_watching(), "entry code didn't wake RCU");

#ifdef CONFIG_MATH_EMULATION
    if (read_cr0() & X86_CR0_EM) {
        struct math_emu_info info = { };

        conditional_sti(regs);

        info.regs = regs;
        math_emulate(&info);
        return;
    }
#endif
    fpu__restore(&current->thread.fpu); /* interrupts still off */
#ifdef CONFIG_X86_32
    conditional_sti(regs);
#endif
}
NOKPROBE_SYMBOL(do_device_not_available);

void fpu__restore(struct fpu *fpu)
{
    fpu__activate_curr(fpu);

    /* Avoid __kernel_fpu_begin() right after fpregs_activate() */
    kernel_fpu_disable();
    fpregs_activate(fpu);
    copy_kernel_to_fpregs(&fpu->state);
    kernel_fpu_enable();
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(fpu__restore);
```

Seems like it just initilizes a fpu context for current process to run which is matched with **"loads the new FPU context for the current process"**, but there is no **"saves the current FPU context into the old task’s state save area"**, I am so confused, where does **"saves the current FPU context into the old task’s state save area"** happen? Please help!

Comment: dotraplinkage saves fpu state for all traps

Comment: @stark, `#define dotraplinkage __visible`, `dotraplinkage` equals to `__visible`, how could it saves fpu state for all traps?

Comment: sry. meant all context switches but copied the wrong thing. All this stuff seems to have changed recently and depends on fast save CPU instructions like XSAVEOPT.  See for example https://lkml.org/lkml/2021/6/18/780

Comment: @stark, so, could you give a more specific explanation for when and where will the Linux kernel uses XSAVEOPT to achive Lazy FPU Save/Restore?